# Get sharepoint Online data in Windows 8.1/10 Universal apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, universal-apps-8.1-10

How to get SharePoint online list data in my windows 8.1 Universal apps?

I want to do crud operations in SharePoint list data.

I have tried CSOM for that but no work.
My CSOM code is:

```
string url = "Office 365 Url";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
   clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("administator id", "password");
   clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

   Web web = clientContext.Web;

   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
   clientContext.Load(web);
   clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

   Title.Text = web.Title;

}
```

But this constantly gives me below error:

> The property or the field "Title" has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

I have referred this link:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/efd12f11-cdb3-4b28-a9e0-32bfab71a419/windows-phone-81-sdk-for-sharepoint-csom?forum=sharepointdevelopment

I don't want to use REST api in my code.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, got answer after long effort.

```
string url = "Office 365 Url"; 
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
   clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("administator id", "password");
   clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

   Web web = clientContext.Web;

   clientContext.Load(web);
   var webTask = clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

   webTask.Wait();
   Title.Text = web.Title;

}
```

Just need to wait **ExecuteQueryAsync()** method.

Comment: its work for me...

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs since `Title` property is not retrieved when you try to access it. [ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj168848%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is *asynchronous* operation and you could utilize [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait until Web is loaded.

The below example demonstrates how to invoke `ClientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync` method and wait until `Web` is loaded:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
    ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    var web = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(web);
    var webTask = ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync();
    webTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        var webTitle = web.Title;
    });
}
```

### References

[Consuming the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for reply...But it throws same error.

Comment: please help me more to assign `web.Title` to `Title.Text`. When trying to assign within `ContinueWith((t)` it throws exception **The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))**

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly load the title property:

```
string url = "Office 365 Url";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{
   clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("administator id", "password");
   clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;

   Web web = clientContext.Web;

   clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
   clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Title);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

   Title.Text = web.Title;

}
```

Comment: Tried that buddy... Unfortunately, got same error...

Comment: Updated to not make use of the Async method for executing queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems incomplete or wrong. As per my understanding you need to give the parameter of success and fail method name in the [`ExecuteQueryAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj168848(v=office.15).aspx) call.

I think once you change `ExecuteQueryAsync` to `ExecuteQuery`, you will get your result.

You can refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx) link for basic CRUD operation in SharePoint 2013 using Client side library.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In windows 8.1,You have to use WINRT framework. You have to attach `dlls` from 16 hive. so in that case you can't get `ExecuteQuery`. You have to use `ExecuteQueryAsync`.

Comment: Then you need to take a look at this method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj168848(v=office.15).aspx . In that you specify success callback and fail callback.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/738008/Programming-Efficiently-with-the-SharePoint-Client This might help you as well.

Comment: Tried that but not worked...

Comment: Did you try putting `await` keyword before  `ExecuteQueryAsync`?

Comment: Yes...but still it throws same error.